# Blazor not working validations in custom component

Tags: c#, components, blazor

i have a little problem with custom component in blazor server side. I try create my custom DateTime component. And when i have nullable input on enter is everything fine. I fill name and form is still valid. When i write something invalid to the date input, it's show me validation its ok. But when i delete the invalid value validation is hidden but form is still invalid.

```
@inherits InputBase<DateTime?>

<input value="@CurrentValue" @onchange="((v) => OnChange(v))" class="form-control" />
<ValidationMessage TValue="DateTime?" For="@ValueExpression" />


@code {
    public async Task OnChange(ChangeEventArgs changeEventArgs)
    {
        CurrentValueAsString = changeEventArgs.Value?.ToString();
        await Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    protected override bool TryParseValueFromString(string? value, [MaybeNullWhen(false)] out DateTime? result, [NotNullWhen(false)] out string validationErrorMessage)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
        {
            result = Value;
            validationErrorMessage = string.Empty;
            return true;
        }

        if (DateTime.TryParse(value, out DateTime output))
        {
            result = output;
            validationErrorMessage = string.Empty;
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            result = null;
            validationErrorMessage = "Field hasn't right format";
            return false;
        }   
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YmFZu.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1dQ7.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQWdn.png)

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Did you try "StateHasChanged()" before the dateTime.tryParse() if your data it's ok, and debuggind you'r seeing that you are doing everything fine, could be that you need to make the state change to the ui

Comment: @LeandroToloza thank you for response. Yea i try it and it doesn't help. One interesting thing is when i try insert null (empty value) to the input. Because it doesnt call TryParseValueFromString. Maybe this is the problem. But i don't know how repair it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my test page for your component.  It only reports a validation error when the input contains an invalid entry.  I can't see what's wrong, so I'm assuming there's a problem in your form???

```
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<EditForm EditContext=this.editContext OnInvalidSubmit=this.InvalidSubmit OnValidSubmit=this.ValidSubmit>
    Custom Date: <CustomDate @bind-Value=this.model.Date></CustomDate>
    <ValidationSummary />
    <button class="btn btn-success">Submit </button>
</EditForm>

@code {
    private Model model = new();
    private EditContext? editContext;

    private void InvalidSubmit()
    {
        var c = editContext?.Validate();
        var x = true;
    }

    private void ValidSubmit()
    {
        var c = editContext?.Validate();
        var x = true;
    }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        editContext = new EditContext(model);
        base.OnInitialized();
    }

    public class Model
    {
        public DateTime? Date { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. You have right. The problem was with editform component from third party library. Thanks